# What is the shortcut in Eclipse to open a resource name referenced in another file?

Tags: eclipse

In Intellij if we press Ctrl and click on the class name, the class will open. Is there a shortcut same as that in Eclipse?

Comment: you don't need stack over flow for this question

Comment: Google must give an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is the same. Click Ctrl, put mouse over and it will become a link